# Unable to run the program that uses Streamlit module in Pycharm

Tags: python, error-handling

Warning: to view this Streamlit app on a browser, run it with the following
command:

```
`streamlit run C:\Users\---------\PycharmProjects\Portfolio Website\venv\website.py [ARGUMENTS]`
```

This is the error that I am getting, tried running in the Cmd Prompt,

`streamlit run C:\Users\---------\PycharmProjects\Portfolio Website\venv\website.py`

not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes to help debugging it is best to run a really simple example. Could you try changing your working directory to where your file is and run just this and see if it works?

```
import streamlit as st

st.title('Hello World')
```

`streamlit run  <name_of_file>.py`